# How to create Crystal Report template In visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have many reports in which header section is the same. I want to create a common template of Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2010 where I can put my common header and use this template in all other reports.

I know that I can create report template using template field object, but I cannot see  this type of item in my **Crystal Reports -> Insert** menu.

So my question is: how is it possible to create Crystal Report Template In visual studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Using Crystal Report you can create a Report Template as your requirement (Data Connection is not required, just objects can be added like logo, headers, footers, etc.,). After completing save as .rpt. Whenever u need to create a new report in this format, u can import this report using **Template Expert**. 
Pls look at this [Tutorial](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/index?rid=/library/uuid/e0bd989a-c049-2e10-ae8d-81a786b083a3&overridelayout=true) for more details.
EDIT :
If you want to do this in visual studio,
I can suggest you to create a Format Report and save as .rpt 
while you open a new report select ***From an Existing Report*** and browse the Format Report u made already. Hence the new report which your created will looks like your format report.

Comment: thanks hariharan for your answer, i knew it already but i am working with **Visual studio 2010 with crystal report** in which currently i am not able to create template means i have not any option like **template expert**,so my question is **how to create template of crystal report in visual studio 2010?**

Comment: thanks hariharan for your quick response,But in this approach is it possible to change one .rpt file and it effects all other file.for e.g. i create format report in which header contains PartyName,and Party address after that i create 5 new reports from my formate report.after some time i remove Party Address field from format report so is it also remove from my all other report or not?

Comment: No it wont. This method can be used just to maintain the the alignment and objects like Logo, Text objects in header and footer, etc., If you want to effect the changes, u need to use Sub-Reports inside a main report

Comment: thanks hariharan,yes it is possible using sub reoprt.but do u know what is issue behind invisible template expert and template object in visual studio 2010?

Comment: Not sure may be due to some product registration. Your Crystal Report is a registered version?